# How can I get descendants of descendant in Linq?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

**EDIT:** So I have an XML file which I need to parse. After research, I have been able to get the first set of nodes with out issue, and I really like the way I can return them.

I have been able to get the immediate Child of `<Project>`. But getting the next descendants (`<tree>` & `<branch`), has not been quite so fruitful, and I finally decided to ask after google and R+D myself... If possible I'd like to have the similar class style output as shown below, even if the code is restructured.

XML Structure

```
<Projects>
 <Project AccessTag="">
  <Title></Title>
  <ReaderURL></ReaderURL>
  <Status></Status>
  <tree>
   <branch></branch>
  </tree>
 </Project>
</Projects>
```

Code

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(this.XMLFile);
var project = (
  from p in xml.Descendants("Project")
  where p.Attribute("AccessTag").Value == Trigger
  select new {
    title = p.Element("Title").Value,
    reader = p.Element("ReaderURL").Value,
    status = p.Element("Status").Value
    }).Single();
// output is project.title, project.reader, etc
```

Edit: After all the research I did, and variations based off below answers, my  finished code is now as follows, and returns a `var` result similar to that of a `class`. After working on the project further. I ended up with many `<tree>` and `<branch>` elements as child nodes of the parent `<Project>` element. Which each tree element has a unique number attribute.

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(this.XMLFile);

var resulted = xml.Descendants("Project")
  .Where(a => (string)a.Attribute("AccessTag") == Trigger)
  .Select(a => new {
    Title = (string)a.Element("Title"),
    ReaderURL = (string)a.Element("ReaderURL"),
    Status = (string)a.Element("Status"),

    Tree = a.Elements("tree")
      .Where(b => (string)b.Attribute("number") == Num)
      .Select(b => new {...}).Single()
  }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Like mentioned below, I spent a couple minutes in wonder and debugging before I remembered to use `.Single()` on the 2nd `.Select()` clause. As I only wanted one result returned ( and I also am not familiar with going through Enumerators yet ). Thanks for the responses, and help everyone!

Comment: When you say descendants, you mean the value of the `tree` and/or `branch` nodes?

Comment: Yes, 'twas what I meant. Updated for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

```
var result = xml.Descendants("Project")
           .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("AccessTag") == "Trigger")
           .Select(x => new
  {
     Title = (string)x.Element("Title"),
     ReaderURL = (string)x.Element("ReaderURL"),
     Status = (string)x.Element("Status"),
     Branch = x.Descendants("tree") //Here are fetching the Descendants
              .Select(z => (string)z.Element("branch")).FirstOrDefault()
   }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Please note I am using `FirstOrDefault` while fetching `Branch` as I am considering you need just the first Branch element, if that is not the case, replace FirstOrDefault with `ToList()` and it will return all the branch elements.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do like this:

```
from p in xml.Descendants("Project")
from t in p.Descendants("tree") // selecting descendant node tree of Project
  where p.Attribute("AccessTag").Value == Trigger
  select new {
    title = p.Element("Title").Value,
    reader = p.Element("ReaderURL").Value,
    status = p.Element("Status").Value,
    branch = t.Element("branch").Value // select value here
    }).Single();
```

Comment: Assuming there is only 1 `<tree>` in the whole XML, this would be fine.

Comment: @Tony Arnold what you mean?

Comment: If there was more then a single tree sub node. Like `<tree><branch></branch></tree><tree>...</tree><tree>...</tree>`

Comment: @Tony Arnold remove the call of ``Single()``, then it will get all ``<tree>`` subnodes of that ``<Project>`` node

Answer (score 0):

You can use element rather than descendants...

```
var root = xml.Element("Projects").Element("Project")
              .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("AccessTag") == "Trigger")
              .Select(x => {...});
```