# In C# how would I use xml.linq to grab values nested in xml?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Sorry if this has been asked I can't find it.
I'm not great with XML but am trying to work with it

The xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Config>
  <commands>
    <command name="check">
      <stdout>output_value</stdout>
    </command>
    <command name="ping http://192.168.1.1">
      <stdout>result</stdout>
    </command>
    <command name="config">
      <stdout>Initialized</stdout>
      <stdout>listen on http://127.0.0.1:8888</stdout>
      <stdout>loaded</stdout>
      <stdout>verified</stdout>
      <stdout>connected</stdout>
      <stdout>connection INITIALIZED</stdout>
      <stdout>load complete</stdout>
    </command>
    <command name="connection">
      <stdout>Got connection</stdout>
    </command>
  </commands>
</Config>
```

basically I am trying to get where the text is in the stdout under each command.

I've figured out I can get where it says "name of command" by doing

```
XDocument xd = XDocument.Load("config.xml");
var commandcheck = from paths in xd.Decendants(xmln)
                   select paths.Attribute(attrb).value
foreach(var paths in commandcheck)
{
   Console.WriteLine(paths)
}
```

Basically how I am attempting to parse and display this data is in the format of

```
Command name Check
stdout output_value

command name config
stdout initialized
stdout listen
stdout loaded
```

and so on

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please show a slightly more realistic XML document and your desired output too please?

Comment: check this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981629/how-can-i-get-descendants-of-descendant-in-linq and this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985418/linq-to-xml-extract-nested-elements

Comment: @user10847 - Can you please provide your desired output for this improved XML too please?

Comment: Basically I'm trying to make a loop that goes through commands and gets then name,  then in that loop another loop to list the stdout values under the name before moving to the next name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Element` method to get your desire output.

```
var textcheck = from paths in xd.Descendants("command") select paths.Element("commandoutput").Value;
foreach (var paths in textcheck)
{
   Console.WriteLine(paths);//Here you get output as 'TEXT'
}
```